# how can I remove the 3D-Look of the Spinbox Up and Down Buttons in python (tkinter)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So, how can I remove that 3d-Look from the up- and down arrows inside a spinbox in python (tkinter)?
I hope you know what I mean.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read through the documentation and have you tried some of the spinbox-specific options?

Comment: I tried `relief=FLAT` and read the documentation, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The spinbox has options named `buttondownrelief` and `buttonuprelief`, which are the reliefs to use for the down and up buttons. Setting them to `"flat"` will remove the 3D-look on some platforms.

Comment: I tried it, but I didn't work. Do the up and down buttons have an own keyword for their borderradius?

Comment: @McMonocle: no, they do not.